# Find the second highest variable in array

Tags: php

I would like to find the second highest variable in an array.

**For example if I have:**

```
$cookies = array(
                "chocolate" => "20",
                "vanilla" => "14",
                "strawberry" => "18",
                "raspberry" => "19",
                "bluebery" => "29"
);
```

I can use `max($cookies)` to find the highest variable, which is `"bluebery" => "29"`.

**But how do I find the second highest?** `"chocolate" => "20"`

Comment: Option one: Remove max element from array and look for maximum again. Second: Order array and take the second element.

Comment: What approaches have you tried?  A couple ideas come to mind: You could step through the array and pick out the highest two, similar to picking the highed one.  Another is that you could sort and pick the second one.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sort it and get the second item is the easiest way:

```
arsort($cookies);
$keys = array_keys($cookies);

echo $keys[1]; // chocolate
echo $cookies[$keys[1]]; // 20
```

If you want a more efficient way, you can also do it manually, by keeping track of both the highest and second-highest items at the same time:

```
function secondMax($arr) {
    $max = $second = 0;
    $maxKey = $secondKey = null;

    foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
        if($value > $max) {
            $second = $max;
            $secondKey = $maxKey;
            $max = $value;
            $maxKey = $key;
        } elseif($value > $second) {
            $second = $value;
            $secondKey = $key;
        }
    }

    return array($secondKey, $second);
}
```

Usage:

```
$second = secondMax($cookies);
echo "{$second[0]} => {$second[1]}"; // chocolate => 20
```

Comment: Good solution, but I'm skeptic that looping yourself is more efficient than the native, compiled functions?

Comment: $secondMax Undefined for function

Comment: @HardyMathew: Thank you; fixed, probably.

Answer (score 5):

For fun you could use [`max()`](http://php.net/max) twice :)

For example:

- Duplicate the array
- Run `max()`
- Remove the *max*
- Run `max()` again

The alternative would to sort the array based on values and get the second element of the array. I'd be curious which is *faster*. Likely the sort.

Answer (score 2):

```
arsort($cookies) AND array_shift($cookies) AND list($k, $v) = each($cookies);
echo "$k => $v"; // chocolate => 20
```

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
asort($cookies);
end($cookies);
prev($cookies);
list($key,$value) = each($cookies);
```

or reverse it

```
arsort($cookies);
reset($cookies);
next($cookies);
list($key,$value) = each($cookies);
```

** **Edit** **

I thought I'd share this anyway, if someone would stumble across this and need it :

```
/**
 * Returns the key => value pair with the specific rank.
 * if $rank is 0, falase is returned. If $rank is positive,
 * then the $rank th smallest pair is returned. If $rank
 * is negative, then the $rank th biggest pair is returned.
 * If $rank range is outside the size of the array, false
 * is returned. If a callable function is provided, it will
 * be used to sort the data. If $keySort is true, then the
 * data will be sorted by keys instead (the callback functions
 * will receive the keys to compare instead of values)
 * 
 * @param $data array
 * @param $rank int
 * @param $cmd_function callable (optional)
 * @param $keySort boolean (optional)
 * @return array            the key => value pair or false
 */
function findByRank($data, $rank, $cmd_function = null, $keySort = false) {
    if (($rank == 0) || (abs($rank) > count($data))) {
        return false;
    }
    $sort = ($keySort?'k':'a').'sort';
    if ($cmd_function != null) {
        $sort = 'u'.$sort;
        $sort($data, $cmd_function);
    } else {
        $sort($data);
    }

    if ($rank > 0) {
        reset($data);
        $next = 'next';
    } else {
        end($data);
        $next = 'prev';
        $rank = abs($rank);
    }
    while (--$rank > 0) $next($data);
    return each($data);
}




$cookies = array(
                "chocolate" => "20",
                "vanilla" => "14",
                "strawberry" => "18",
                "raspberry" => "19",
                "bluebery" => "29"
);

header('Content-type:text/plain; charset=utf-8');
var_dump(findByRank($cookies, -10));  // -> false
var_dump(findByRank($cookies, -2));   // -> 'chocolate' key=>value pair
var_dump(findByRank($cookies, -1));   // -> 'blueberry' key=>value pair
var_dump(findByRank($cookies, 0));    // -> false
var_dump(findByRank($cookies, 1));    // -> 'vanilla' key=>value pair
var_dump(findByRank($cookies, 3));    // -> 'raspberry' key=>value pair
```

Comment: `ksort` sorts by key. Do you mean `asort`?

Comment: oops, yes, I was thinking "sort preserving key assocations", but `asort` is the correct function, yes

Answer (score 1):

```
rsort($cookies);
echo $cookies[1];
```

Comment: you can't get the keys with that, though.

Answer (score 0):

Sort the array descending and take the second value. Or, to be save, take the first value and go through the array until you find a smaller one.

Answer (score 0):

Check this URL

http://maheshbokkisam.blogspot.in/2013/04/find-nth-highest-value-in-array-without.html

Find  Nth/ N th highest value from given array without using any sorting in PHP

```
$ar  =  array(23,56,87,12,98,85,24,54,99,100,1,4,5,2,76,37,92);

$n   = count($ar) - 5;

for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++){
    // Get the max value from array // get the Nth value from last loop
    echo $a = max($ar); 

    echo "<br /><pre>"; print_r($ar);

    $ar = array_flip($ar);    // Flip the array
    //print_r($ar);

    unset($ar[$a]);           // Unset the max value from array
    //print_r($ar);

    $ar = array_flip($ar);    // Flip the array
    echo "</pre>";
    echo "<hr />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function second_largest($arr)
{
    sort($arr, SORT_NUMERIC);

    return($arr[count($arr) - 2]);
}

//echo 3

echo second_largest(array(0, 3, 4, 1, 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

 // Finding Second highest number (In case of index of array is random)
$arr = [-5 => 33, -4 => -2, 8 => 0, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44];
$max = -INF;
$secondMax = -INF;
$size = sizeof($arr);
if ($size > 1) {
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        echo "KEY-> ", $key, "VALUE->", $value, "\n";
        if ($value > $max) {
            $max = $value;
        } else {
            if ($value < $max && $value > $secondMax) {
                $secondMax = $value;
            }
        }
    }
} else if ($size == 0) {
    $max = "No Max element";
    $secondMax = "No Second highest element";
} else {
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        $max = $arr[$key];
        $secondMax = "No second highest element";
    }
}

echo "maxvalue = ", $max, "\n";
echo "secondmax =", $secondMax;
```